# Should model extends entity in domain - data layer

Tags: model, entity, clean-architecture

In domain - data - presentation layer, there are model and entity. In my understanding, entity is only data field and model is data field that can have some logic like json mapper.

But, is model class should extends entity class? Should data field in model place in entity class? Can we have only model class?

Answer (score 0):

The domain, persistence and presentation model serve different clients and should therefore be separated. Sometime it's anoying to implement 3 different models that almost look identical, but I would like to place emphasis on "almost" as I would like to show you now.

#### Domain model

The domain model implements application agnostic logic. That is domain-specific logic that doesn't change between different applications in the domain. E.g. if you have a `Person` class with a property birthday, you might want to ask the person how old he/she is at a specific point in time.

```
 public class Person {
     private LocalDate birthday;

     public int getAge(Clock clockAtTime){
         Instant instant = clockAtTime.getInstant();

         // calculate the age at the given point in time
         // Also handle exception cases like person not born yet (age < 0)
     }
 }
```

The logic above is very general and can be even used in differnt domains. It doesn't matter if you are implementing a shopping application and you have to verify that the customer has a legal age or if you implement a film rental application that must decide which films a person is allowed to watch depending on his/her age. In the latter you might also want to implement a FilmRating class that applies [rating rules](https://www.motionpictures.org/film-ratings/) like "PG-13" or "NC-17".

#### persistence model

The persistence model is made for persistence purposes. In Java it might contain JPA annotations that describe how fields are mapped to a relational database. The structure of this model can be very similar to the domain model, but it doesn't have to. E.g. the domain model `Person` might have a property `address` of type `Address`, which has differnt properties like "street", "zip" and "city".

```
 // In the domain model...

 public class Persion {
      private String firstname;
      private String lastname;
      private Address address;
 }

 public class Address {
      private String street;
      private String zipCode;
      private String city;
 }
```

For persistence purposes you might want to save the "street", "zip" and "city" in the same table as the person's attributes.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name ="person")
 public class PersonJPA {

     @Column(name="firstname", length=50)
     private String firstname;

     @Column(name="lastname", length=50)
     private String lastname;

     @Column(name="addressStreet", length=50)
     private String addressStreet;

     @Column(name="addressStreet", length=12)
     private String addressZip;

     @Column(name="addressStreet", length=30)
     private String addressCity;
 }
```

Sure in JPA you can also use an `@Embeddable` annotation to solve this, but even then it can be wise to separate the models.

The persistence model might not contain domain model properties that are derived from others like the age in the example above. This clear separation is better then mixing both models and then using yet another annotation to tell the persistence framework that a property should not be persisted (like @Transient in JPA). The properties in the persistence model might also be a differnt type then the one in the domain model. E.g. in the domain model you might have an `EMail` class that can give you the domain and the name of the email, but in the persistence model you only have one string, because you don't need to search an email by a domain.

#### presentation model

The presentation model is made for presentation purposes. It usually contains simple types like string. So if you have an `Amount` class in your domain that has a value property of type `BigDecimal` you will format it to a string representation in the presentation model, depending on language settings. Vice versa you will parse a string in the presentation model before sending the value to a use case. The component that does the formatting and parsing is usually called the presenter.

---

#### Conclusion

- If you separate the 3 models you honor the single responsibility principle. It prevents you from breaking something in another model when you only want to make a modification to one model.
- Yes ,you will end up writing more code, but each of the 3 different classes will become easier, because you don't mix a lot of concerns.
- Each model can be tested in isolation, so that your tests will immediatly show your where an issue was introduced.
- Since you have 3 models for 3 different purposes you can work on one model while a colleague can work on another without having merge conflicts.